# Pandas shift base on multiple columns combination

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF as follows:

| month | shop_id | item_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 19 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 27 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 19 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 27 | 2 |

I want to use `shift()` so that the new column is the combination of `shop_id` and `item_id` from the previous month. This is the desired result:

| month | shop_id | item_id | sales | last_month_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 19 | 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 0 | 27 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 19 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 27 | 2 | 1 |

All the guides I see are just shift by rows, not based on any column. How can I do that?

Comment: `df.groupby(['shop_id','item_id'])['sales'].shift()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape values by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), shifting, reshape back and add new column to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.pivot(['month','shop_id'],'item_id', 'sales').shift().stack().rename('last_month_sale')
df = df.join(s, on=['month','shop_id','item_id'])
print (df)
   month  shop_id  item_id  sales  last_month_sale
0      1        0       19      1              NaN
1      1        0       27      1              NaN
2      2        1       19      2              1.0
3      2        1       27      2              1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something new `drop_duplicates` with `reindex`

```
df['new'] = df.drop_duplicates(['month','shop_id']).sales.shift().reindex(df.index,method = 'ffill')
Out[31]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```